# XFCE Audio Mixer Glitching (pavucontrol) - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, xfce, webcam, microphone

I'm having trouble using a microphone, webcam and even listening to audios.
For example WhatsApp web version does not output the audios you send me using Mozilla Firefox.
And in the audio mixer there are glitches, like the video I added here.
Does anyone know any solution for configuring audio devices?

https://vimeo.com/436156197

Comment: Your link is broken - so nothing to see.

Comment: @kanehekili thank you to reply, I fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after tests I fix my trouble showing only "Virtual Streams" the WhatsApp aúdio back do works and my mic after this not stop of works more too. Maybe can a little bug.

[image: pavucontrol]